# UITheme and UIThemeDisplayed not working correctly for VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I have a lightning component, in which I am using Iframe from where I am opening a VF Page, on that VF page, I am trying to get UITheme which is showing as **Theme3** even if I am doing it through Lightning Experience. Is there any bug for the same or I ma doing some thing wrong?

Comment: I too had issues with UIThemeDisplayed and UITheme when using them inline with visualforce.  Some suggest to do the detection on the server-side as a workaround (though I am not posting this as an answer because I have not tested it).  Try doing the detection in the controller using String theme = UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed();
and then expose that String to your page.

Comment: I did that, still system is capturing Theme3 when I am in Lightning

Comment: The iframe in which the VF page is running is not Lightning Experience, that's why you're getting Theme3.

Comment: Is there a way to get correct UITheme ? I suppose it is a bug at salesforce end if I am using Iframe on lightning component where I have VF embedded , then UI theme showing as Theme3 instaed of Theme4d